# jQuery: selectors with OR condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got following code:

```
$('table.tableElements thead|tbody tr').children().hover(function(){
    //    How can I do this ↑
});
```

I'd like to catch all `tr's` of `thead` **OR** `tbody` but not `tfoot`.
How can I do this?

Comment: 3 identical answers, I have the least rep so accept mine. Just kidding :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `not` method to exclude the `tfoot` rows:

```
$('table.tableElements tr').not('tfoot tr').children().hover(function(){
    // code....
});
```

Comment: @Felix Kling: I am not sure about the performance either; that is what came to my mind while reading the question.

Comment: Don't know why, but other suggested methods did not work for me. This works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table.tableElements thead tr, table.tableElements tbody tr ')
```

A bit verbose, but will work.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table.tableElements thead tr, table.tableElements tbody tr').children().hover(function() {

});
```

Comment: @BoltClock - Yeah I saw that. 4 hours sleep in 2 days can't be good for you. The perks of working for an advertising agency. Good night gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table.tableElements thead tr, table.tableElements tbody tr')
```